# scanf issue when reading double

Tags: c, gcc, double, user-input, scanf

I'm using MinGW on windows 7 to compile C files.

My problem is a strange behaviour with `scanf()` to read `double`s from user input.

My code:

```
int main() {

   double radius = 0;
   double pi = 3.14159;

   scanf("%lf \n", &radius); // after the input, it continues waiting... 
   radius = ((radius * radius) * pi);
   printf("A=%.4lf\n", radius);  
   return 0;    
}
```

When I run this program it's necessary input a value, let's suppose `100.64`, the normal behaviour is press enter and the program should continue and show the result, but the program stays waiting for more input. If I type 0 and press enter again, the program continues normal.

```
>area.exe
100.64  <-- doesn't proceed after press enter
0 <-- needs input another value, then press enter
A=31819.3103 <-- the result
```

Why scanf doesn't proceed with the first input? Why it needs more?

Obs: in my Linux this doesn't occur.

```
gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 4.9.2
```

Comment: May I suggest `int main()` --> `int main(void)`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh why? there is difference in this case?

Comment: Actually the later one is recommended by the `C` standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, change

```
  scanf("%lf \n", &radius);
```

to

```
  scanf("%lf", &radius);
```

Otherwise, with a format string having `whitespace`, `scanf()` will behave as below (quoted from `C11`, chapter `§7.21.6.2`, paragraph 5)

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read.

So, to provide the "non-white-space character" to end the *scanning*, you need to input a `0` (basically, a non-whitespace character).

Please check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same solution for a little bit different problem (just in type of variable)

[Why does scanf ask for input twice, but just in the first loop iteration only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921098/why-does-scanf-ask-for-input-twice-but-just-in-the-first-loop-iteration-only)

When you include the whitespace in the scanf

The program will wait until you enter a blank space or any other value in it, so the program will continue as normal, but the blank space or any value that you entered will not be used anyway.