# Why does scanf ask for input twice, but just in the first loop iteration only?

Tags: c, scanf

First of all, this may seem duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15740024/1275831) question, but in my case, why did this only happen in the 1st loop iteration (input for the 1st array element). Why not all?

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Input a[%d]:\n", i);
        int x = scanf("%d ", &a[i]);    // notice the white-space after %d
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

Output example:

```
Input a[0]:
1
2
Input a[1]:
3
Input a[2]:
4
Input a[3]:
5
Input a[4]:
6
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
a[3]=4
a[4]=5
```

Why did it ask for input twice only for `a[0]` but not for the rest, and also why the value assigned to `a[1-5]` is the value that was input in the one loop iteration before it?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15740124/1275831) answer, but I still don't understand why it didn't ask for input twice in each loop. Any clear explanation?

Comment: `scanf("%d "` --> `scanf("%d"`  (drop space).  Extra space tells `scanf()` to keep looking until non-white space detected.

Comment: please **do not use `scanf()`.** It's extremely hard to use correctly, and it **will** cause subtle, hard-to-track-down bugs. If you want to get one item per line from stdin, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: you maybe right about `scanf()` vs `fgets()`, but I'm trying to understand the subtle, hard-to-track-down bugs here. :)

Comment: One bug in the code is the returned value from the call to scanf() needs to be properly checked suggest: 'if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &a[i]) ) (// handle error }

Comment: the compiler raises 3 warnings: 1) unused variable x  2) unused parameter argc  3) unused parameter argv    Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )

Comment: the code contains the magic number '5'  suggest #define MAX_A_LEN (5) then using that name in all instances where '5' currently is written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case,

```
 scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
```

after *scanning* an integer, `scanf()` needs to match the white space, and any number of white space **until** a non-white space character is required to complete the match.

So, for the first time, the second input is the non-white space, which terminates the *scan*, but left in the buffer (remains unread) for the next *scan*.

Next time onwards, the last input (left in the buffer) is considered as the *scanned* input , and the current input works as the terminator, just to be left in the buffer and so on.

So, the very last input (`6`), is never actually read into the array, that remains as a mere *terminator*. The sequential first five inputs are considered.
Just to make it clear, quoting from `C11`, chapter `§7.21.6.2`, paragraph (5), *emphasis mine*

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input ***up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread)***, or until no more characters can be read.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If only I had known that "the second input is the non-white space, which terminates the scan, but left in the buffer (remains unread) ", I would have been able to answered this my self. So, could you give me some references in standard document or any other article that explain how the input/output buffer works?

Answer (score 0):

[@Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921143/2410359) very nicely explained about `scanf()`.

To clarify the user experience, the tricky additional part is that `stdin` is typically line *buffered*.  That means none of the user typing is given to `stdin` until  <kbd>Enter</kbd> or EOF occurs.  That is why the first `scanf()` did not return when `2` was typed (the non-white-space sought by directive `" "` in `scanf("%d ",...`).  User has to type `2` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, *then* `stdin` gets both `"2\n"`.  *Then* `scanf()` sees the `2`, leaves it unread in `stdin` and then returns.

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1) raises no compiler warnings I.E. complies cleanly

2) properly handles any error condition with scanf()

3) properly handles the program exit with 'return(0);'

4) includes stdlib.h for exit() and EXIT_FAILURE

5) properly declares the main() function when the optional parameters argc and argv are not used.

6) corrects the problem with the format string in scanf()

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h> // exit and EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_A_LEN (5)

int main( void )
{
    int a[ MAX_A_LEN ];
    int i; // loop index

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_A_LEN; i++)
    {
        printf("Input a[%d]:\n", i);
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &a[i]) )    
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_A_LEN; ++i)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```